# How not to add control of an html element that has formControlName?

Tags: html, angular, typescript, forms

I am developing a frontend project. In that project I have different conditions. The conditions are effecting  the input. I mean If user click a spesific button, some of the inputs are hidden.

In html file every input has formControlName as below:

```
 <input id="age" matInput formControlName="age" [disabled]="isSelected" required placeholder="your age" maxlength="2">
```

**If I DO NOT WRITE the code below in .ts file**

```
this.personalInformationForm.addControl("age", new FormControl({ value: null, disabled: this.isDisabled("age") }));
```

But the problem is here;

If I do not create a control in .ts file, I am given an error as follows

***ERROR Error: Cannot find control with name: 'age'***

How can I handle this issue?

Comment: Have you thought of the [FormBuilder](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms#using-the-formbuilder-service-to-generate-controls) of Angular?

Comment: You also have a possibility of `removeControl()` function. On that specific case you can also remove that `formControl`.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should go with Async Validator [Ex.](https://codinglatte.com/posts/angular/how-to-add-async-validators-to-an-angular-reactive-form/)

I might be wrong.